# django list_filter filter by id display by name

Tags: python, django

Currently in the admin interface it is possible to filter the projects by company name not the company instance in the database. Because of that it is impossible to filter out the projects of one specific company if there are multiple companies with the same name.

Please fix it - make it possible to filter projects by actual companies in the database (company name should still be visible in the filter options.

```
list_filter = ('company__name',) 
#I change and become
list_filter = ('company__id',)
```

But now, the filter displays the id, but name need. How do I display by name but filter by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [custom filter class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). Something like that might work for you:

```
class CompanyListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('company')
    parameter_name = 'company_id'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        # generate the list of choices
        companies = Company.objects.all()
        return [(company.pk, company.name) for company in companies]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # filter the queryset by the selected value
        value = self.value()
        if value is not None:
            return queryset.filter(company_id=self.value())
        return queryset


class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # add the filter to the admin instance
    list_filter = (CompanyListFilter,)
```

Comment: Button all. to display all the records.

Comment: I've edited the answer... Feel free to adjust the `queryset` method where the filtering happens to your needs...